# Draw faster circles with Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have an exercise wherein I have to draw a lot of circles with Python turtle. I have set `speed(0)` and I am using:

```
from turtle import*
speed(0)
i=0
while i < 360:
    forward(1)
    left(1)
    i+=1
```

to draw circles. It takes so long. Is there any faster way?

Comment: What do you mean by faster. As in code performance or the speed of the turtle? It's not clear what you're trying to do and what you want to do.

Comment: This clearly isn't your actual code, as `i` isn't initialised. This would produce a `NameError`. Please give your real code if you want help. Beyond that, if you want to loop a number of times in Python, counting like that is considered bad practice. Use `for _ in range(360):` instead.

Comment: isnt there something like turtle.circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw fewer segments, so rather than 360 you go for 120:

```
while i < 360:
    forward(3)
    left(3)
    i+=3
```

That will make your circle less smooth, but three times faster to draw.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `turtle.delay()` or `turtle.tracer()` ? See documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.delay) and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer).  These set options for screen refreshing which is responsible for most of the delays.

Answer (score 2):

Turtle has a function for drawing circles and the speed of that is much faster than going in a circle one step at a time.

```
 import turtle
 tina=turtle.Turtle()
 
 tina.circle(70)
```

It will look like this

[image]

If you want to draw your circle even faster, you can try adding a delay block as well.

```
import turtle
tina=turtle.Turtle()

tina.delay(1)
tina.speed(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The circle() method might not be faster, but may be easier to manage:
[turtle.circle()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle)

Answer (score 0):

Use Multithread to draw two semi circles simultaneously.
Initially the turtle will be at (0,0) so just clone the turtle and make them both face in opposite direction by 180° then draw semicircles. The code is below:

```py
from threading import Thread
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)
def semi1(r):
   r.circle(50,180)
def semi2(t):
   t.circle(50,180)

r = t.clone()
r.rt(180)

a = Thread(target=semi1).start()
b = Thread(target=semi2).start()
```

This may draw the circle fast.